# how to merge the below two if condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
if array1.present?
  method_call(array1[:ids])
end

if array2.present?
  method_call(array2[:ids])
end
```

How to make the above code much more simple or in one line?

Comment: If `array1` was an array, then `array1[:ids]` would result in an error.

Comment: If it's really just two lists leave it as it is. It's more readable this way than the current propositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[array1, array].select(&:present?)
               .map { |a| a[:ids] }
               .each(&method(:method_call))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this sort of thing in ruby.  Here's one:

```
[array1, array2].compact.each do |array|
  method_call(array[:ids])
end
```

`compact` will take the `nils` out of the array.

Alternatively...

```
[array1, array2].each do |array|
  method_call(array[:ids]) if array
end
```

Edit:  one-liner?

```
[array1, array2].compact.each {|a| method_call(a[:ids]) }
```

*Though I should point out that if those are actually arrays, then `:id` is not a valid index. If they are hashes, then this example makes more sense.*

Comment: `[].present? == true if []` `#⇒ false`. You have changed the semantics as well.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the same, but bit simpler,

```
[array1, array2].each do |a|
  method_call(a[ids]) if a.present?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is perfectly fine because it is easy to read and to understand. And therefore I am not sure if it would improve by making it any shorter.

If I had to change the code (perhaps our example is just part of a long list of method calls and conditions) I would think about:

- Reordering method calls and conditions

  ```
  method_call(array1[:ids]) if array1.present?
  method_call(array2[:ids]) if array2.present?
  ```
- or introducing a helper method:

  ```
  def call_method(array)
    method_call(array[:ids]) if array.present?
  end

  call_method(array1)
  call_method(array2)
  ```